# How can I flush a file buffer in System Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to flush out a file buffer before executing `$finish` in my simulation.  Is there a file flush command that I can use?  Or must I simply use `$fclose`?  I realize I *can* close the file in this scenario, but I'd like to know if there is a flush command for my future use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Verilog IEEE Std (1364-2001) mentions the `$fflush` system task in section "17.2.6 Flushing output":

> Writes any buffered output to the
>   file(s)

This is of course part of the SystemVerilog IEEE Std (1800-2009) as well (section 21.3.6).